# How to cover Uncover Lines in Test Class?

Tags: apex

```
public with sharing class ACETCobController {

   public List<wrapperCommercial> commercial{get;set;}
   public List<wrapperMedicare> medicare{get;set;}
   public String response{get;set;}
   public List<ACETMemberDetail.COB> cobList{get;set;}
   public ACETMemberDetail MemberDetail{get;set;}
   public Interaction__c Interaction {get;set;}
   public Contact Subject {get;set;}
   public String SourceOriginator {get;set;}
   public ACETHighlightsPanelAdditionalInfo AdditionalInfo {get;set;}
   public Boolean isClaim {get;set;}
   public boolean isCancelCaseCreation{get;set;}
   public ACETCallTopicsDataWrapper wrapper {get;set;}
   //public ACETCaseItemWrapper caseItem{get;set;}
   public string surrogateKey {get; set;}
   public boolean showUpdateSection{get;set;}

    //Commercial section info
    public boolean isCommercialActive{get;set;}
    public string selectCommericial{get;set;}
    public case caseEffectiveDate{get;set;}
    public case caseEndDate{get;set;}
    public string custodialSelect{get;set;}
    public void updateCommercial(){
        showUpdateSection = True;
    }
 public void childconsolefunction(){

        response = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param1');
        system.debug('2323response'+response);
     if(response != null && response != '')
     {
       system.debug('2323response'+response );
       MemberDetail=(ACETMemberDetail)json.deserialize(response,ACETMemberDetail.class);
       system.debug('2323MemberDetail'+MemberDetail);
       cobList = MemberDetail.lstCOB;
       system.debug('cobList '+ cobList );
    }
       }
 public void renderCancelCaseSection(){
        isCancelCaseCreation=true;  
    }

public ACETCobController(){
        caseEffectiveDate = new Case();
        caseEndDate = new Case();
        showUpdateSection = False;

      /*  commercial= new list<wrapperCommercial>();
        wrapperCommercial com1= new wrapperCommercial();
        com1.comName='John Martin';
        com1.comRelationship='Subscriber';
        com1.comMemberOtherInsurance='Yes';
        com1.comInsuranceType='Yes';
        com1.comPrimary='Yes';
        com1.comComemricalEffectiveEnd='02/02/2019';
        com1.comCustodialParent='Both';
        com1.comLastDate='01/02/2019';

        commercial.add(com1);*/
        /*
        wrapperCommercial com2= new wrapperCommercial();
        com2.comRelationship='Spouse';
        com2.comMemberOtherInsurance='';
        com2.comInsuranceType='';
        com2.comPrimary='Yes';
        com2.comComemricalEffectiveEnd='';
        com2.comCustodialParent='Former Spouse';
        com2.comLastDate='';

        commercial.add(com2);
       */


      /*  medicare= new list<wrapperMedicare>();

        wrapperMedicare md1= new wrapperMedicare();
        md1.Name='John Martin';
        md1.Relationship='Subscriber';
        md1.MedicareType='A=Medicare A Only';
        md1.EstimationApplies='Yes';

        medicare.add(md1);*/

         wrapper = new ACETCallTopicsDataWrapper();
         wrapper.CallTopic ='Coordination Of Benefits';
         wrapper.init(); 
         wrapper.CaseObj.Topic__c = 'Coordination Of Benefits';    
         AdditionalInfo = new ACETHighlightsPanelAdditionalInfo();
        /*String providerId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        if(!String.isEmpty(providerId)){
            Provider = [select FirstName, LastName, Tax_ID__c, NPI__c from Contact where Id = :providerId];
        }
        */
        //Get Provider Interaction SFDC Id
       String interactionId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('interactionId');    
        //Check if User is redirected to Member Search page from Provider detail page         
        if (!String.isEmpty(interactionId)){                        
            system.debug('InteractionId: ' + InteractionId);            
            //Query Provider Interaction details
            Interaction = ACETProviderUtility.GetInteractionByID(interactionId);
            SourceOriginator = Interaction.Interaction_Type__c;
            system.debug('Interaction: ' + Interaction + ', SourceOriginator: ' + SourceOriginator);
        }
        String contactId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('contactId');
        if (!String.isEmpty(contactId)){ 
            subject = ACETProviderUtility.GetContactByID(contactId);
        }
        String stradditionalInfo= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('additionalInfo');
        if (!String.isEmpty(contactId)){ 
        AdditionalInfo = (ACETHighlightsPanelAdditionalInfo)JSON.deserialize(stradditionalInfo, ACETHighlightsPanelAdditionalInfo.class);
        }
        surrogateKey = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('SRK');
        if (!String.isEmpty(surrogateKey)){ 
            wrapper.surrogateKey = surrogateKey;
        } 
 }
 public void rerenderPB(){
 }
 public PageReference Save(){
        wrapper.caseObj.Topic__c ='Coordination Of Benefits';
        wrapper.createCase();            
        PageReference caseDetailsReference = new PageReference('/' + wrapper.CaseObj.Id);
        return caseDetailsReference;
    }
 public PageReference SaveAndClose(){
        wrapper.caseObj.Topic__c ='Coordination Of Benefits';
        wrapper.caseObj.Status='Closed';
        //wrapper.caseObj.AutoDoc__c = AutoDoc;
        wrapper.createCase();            
        PageReference caseDetailsReference = new PageReference('/apex/ACETCallTopicSaveAndClose?caseId=' + wrapper.CaseObj.Id);
        system.debug('wrapper.CaseObj.Id  >>>  '+wrapper.CaseObj.Id);
        return caseDetailsReference;
    }     
private class wrapperCommercial{
        public String comName{get;set;}
        public String comRelationship{get;set;}
        public String comDob{get;set;}
        public String comAge{get;set;}
        public String comMemberOtherInsurance{get;set;}
        public String comInsuranceType{get;set;}
        public String comPrimary{get;set;}
        public String comComemricalEffectivestart{get;set;}
        public String comComemricalEffectiveEnd{get;set;}
        public String comCustodialParent{get;set;}
        public String comLastDate{get;set;}
        public String comSource{get;set;}
        public String comComments{get;set;}
        public wrapperCommercial()
        {

        }
}
@TestVisible
private class wrapperMedicare{

        public String Name{get;set;}
        public String Relationship{get;set;}
        public String MedicareType{get;set;}
        public String Dob{get;set;}
        public String Age{get;set;}
        public String MedicarePrimary{get;set;}
        public String CrossoverIndicator{get;set;}
        public String EntitleReason{get;set;}
        public String EstimationApplies{get;set;}
        public String EffectiveStartA{get;set;}
        public String EffectiveEndA{get;set;}
        public String EffectiveStartB{get;set;}
        public String EffectiveEndB{get;set;}
        public String EffectiveStartD{get;set;}
        public String EffectiveEndD{get;set;}
        public String LastUpdate{get;set;}
        public String Source{get;set;}
        public String Comments{get;set;}

    public wrapperMedicare(){

    }
 }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For all these variables, try using **System.assertEquals()**

Example

```
public String myStr{get; set;}
```

Put

```
myStr='test';
System.assertEquals(myStr, 'test');
```

Comment: FYI the syntax is `assertEquals(expected_value, observed_value, '<message>')`. You have expected and observed switched, which can lead to some very confusing error messages.

Comment: I would also suggest that if you have to do this then your either need to evaluate the quality of your tests or the need for those properties as they should be covered organically

Comment: Or one would try assigning values to the getter;setter; according to test criteria(for positive and negative cases)